# How do I use Notepad++ (or other) with msysgit?

Tags: git, configuration, text-editor, notepad++, msysgit

How do I use Notepad++ (or any other editor besides vim) with msysgit?

I tried all of the following to no avail:

```
git config --global core.editor C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

git config --global core.editor C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe

git config --global core.editor C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe
```

Comment: Any error messages?  Have you tried setting the EDITOR environment variable?

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Update 2010-2011:

[zumalifeguard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75129/zumalifeguard)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/2486342#2486342) (upvoted) is simpler than the original one, as it no longer needs a shell wrapper script.

As I explain in "[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/773973/6309)", **I prefer a wrapper, as it is easier to try and switch editors, or change the path of one editor, without having to register said change with a `git config` again**.
But that is just me.

---

*Additional information*: the following solution works with **Cygwin**, while the zuamlifeguard's solution does not.

---

Original answer.

The following:

```sh
C:\prog\git>git config --global core.editor C:/prog/git/npp.sh

C:/prog/git/npp.sh:
#!/bin/sh
"c:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst "$*"
```

does work. Those commands are interpreted as shell script, hence the idea to wrap any windows set of commands in a `sh` script.
(As [Franky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412549/franky) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493#comment51287812_1635493): "Remember to save your `.sh` file with Unix style line endings or receive mysterious error messages!")

More details on the SO question [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564/6309)

Note the '`-multiInst`' option, for ensuring a new instance of notepad++ for each call from Git.

Note also that, if you are using Git on **Cygwin** (and want to [use Notepad++ from Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/168971/use-notepad-from-cygwin-without-having-the-shell-wait-for-an-exit-code)), then [scphantm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425715/scphantm) explains in "[using Notepad++ for Git inside Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10209660/6309)" that you must be aware that:

> `git` is passing it a `cygwin` path and `npp` doesn't know what to do with it

So the script in that case would be:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

Multiple lines for readability:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar \
  -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

With **`"$(cygpath -w "$*")"`** being the important part here.

[Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083704/val) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493?noredirect=1#comment29027434_1635493) (and then deleted) that you should not use `-notabbar` option:

> It makes no good to disable the tab during rebase, but makes a lot of harm to general Notepad usability since `-notab` becomes the default setting and you must `Settings>Preferences>General>TabBar> Hide>uncheck` every time you start notepad after rebase. This is hell. You recommended the hell.

So use rather:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

That is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession \
  -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

---

If you want to place the script '`npp.sh`' in a path with spaces (as in
'`c:\program files\...`',), you have three options:

- Either try to quote the path (single or double quotes), as in:

  ```sh
    git config --global core.editor 'C:/program files/git/npp.sh'
  ```
- or try the [shortname notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/892568/6309) (not fool-proofed):

  ```sh
    git config --global core.editor C:/progra~1/git/npp.sh
  ```
- or (my favorite) place '`npp.sh`' in a directory part of your `%PATH%` environment variable. You would not have then to specify any path for the script.

  ```sh
    git config --global core.editor npp.sh
  ```
- [Steiny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367796/steiny) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493#comment48770355_1635493) having to do:

  ```sh
    git config --global core.editor '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/scripts/npp.sh"'
  ```

Comment: I got this to work by placing npp.sh in the root of my drive (ie - C:/npp.sh).  Any time I try to target a folder with spaces (ie - D:/Program Files (x86)/Git/npp.sh) in it it fails, what's the proper way to escape spaces and/or get this to work?

Comment: put quotes around it.  See how he has quotes around the entire thing in his example?

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations of the above and none work with git.  i have my npp script in my path and if from my cygwin console i type, "npp {file}" npp opens the file just fine, but when i do a "git rebase -i" npp opens with a blank file instead of the merge file.  any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: @scphantm strange. I would advise for posting a new question, with a link to this answer, and many more details (Git version, OS version, npp version, content of the script, ...)

Answer (score 436):

```sh
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Or, for 64-bit Windows and a 32-bit install of Notepad++:

```sh
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Or, the following can be issued on the command line on either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows.  It will pull the location of notepad++.exe from the registry and configure git to use it automatically:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad++.exe" /ve`) DO git config --global core.editor "'%B' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

If you wish to place the above from a .BAT or .CMD file, you must replace %A with %%A and %B with %%B

Comment: works in git extensions too. note that for 64bit windows the entry is `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin`

Comment: The silly thing is that -notabbar will disable the tab bar permanently, not just for that session. When launchin notepad++ normally, you have to go into the settings dialog an enable the tab bar again.

Comment: I had to use: `git config --global core.editor "c\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin"`  ...not sure why.

Comment: git rebase was not rebasing my commits. I was amending them using notepad++.exe. I changed the editor settings of git config as mentioned in this answer and magically git rebase started rebasing. I suspect it is to do with the parameters being passed in to notepad++.exe.

Comment: I have Windows 7 64-bit, msysgit v1.9.2 and Notepad++ v6.6.9 and this worked **PERFECTLY**.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use backslashes if you escape them, i.e. `"C:\\Program..."`

Comment: Any reason why it shall launch a new Notepad++ process, without session, plugins and tab bar? Doesn't it work if it's already running?

Comment: @CoDEmanX Without `-multiInst` it will likely just signal the already running Notepad++ to open the file and then exit immediately. This can be a big problem if whatever calls the editor expects it to return only when done editing (i. e. a synchronous operation, as is the case when calling vi). Try an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i`), for instance. If this still works as expected, then you're fine.

Comment: but how to launch notepad++ within git repo?

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, but with a slight edit: git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin".

Comment: Ofer, I see that the only change you made is changing the forward slashes to backslashes.   Did you do it because the forward slashes didn't work?

Comment: For even cooler integration, add "-ldiff". this will add syntax highlighting

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
git config --global core.editor C:/Progra~1/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

Comment: i did the same.. now how to open notepad++ to commit with message?? what is the commad?? please can you give an example

Comment: Adding the `-multiInst` option is crucial here, like in the other answers.

Comment: This is not good for two reasons. First, if the C: volume is NTFS with the 8.3 filename option turned off, there is no `C:\Progra~1` at all. Second, there may be multiple  `C:\Progra*` directories, so the `~1` suffix is not necessarily the valid one.

Answer (score 6):

```
git config core.editor "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\""
```

Comment: That did the trick for me!  Afterwards the .gitconfig looks like: 
[core]
 editor = \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin

Comment: See highest voted answer, which includes this (I didn't read far enough)

Answer (score 5):

As of [Git for Windows v2.15.0 (October 30th 2017)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#changes-since-git-for-windows-v2150-october-30th-2017) it is now possible to [configure `nano`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/161) or [Notepad++](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/291) as Git's default editor [instead of `vim`](https://www.xkcd.com/378/).

During the installation you'll see the following screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use the approach with PATH variable. Path to Notepad++ is added to system's PATH variable and then core.editor is set like following:

```
git config --global core.editor notepad++
```

Also, you may add some additional parameters for Notepad++:

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad++.exe -multiInst"
```

(as I detailed in "[Git `core.editor` for Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20160115214216/http://starikovs.com/2012/11/06/git-core-editor-windows/)")

And here you can find some options you may use when stating Notepad++ [Command Line Options](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/command-line).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2015**

If you unpack/install Notepad++ into `c:\utils\npp\` and rename notepad++.exe to npp.exe for simplicity, then all you have to do is

```
git config --global core.editor c:/utils/npp/npp.exe
```

No wrapper scripts or other trickery. No need to have Notepad++ in PATH.

Comment: Update 2020: seems that you've missed the options to open new notepad instance. I've used from cmd.exe `git config --global core.editor "c:\\soft\\notepad++\\notepad++.exe -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"` and it is working from both `cmd terminal` and `git bash`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 10 and notepad++, and I was getting this error message:

```
line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' git windows
```

So I make the setup in this way:

```
git config --global core.editor 'C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Cygwin:

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=
fi
Notepad2 ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is not empty, convert to Windows format.

Then I set these variables:

```c
export EDITOR=notepad2.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/notepad2.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/2973070/editor)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions,

1. First make sure you have [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.3.html) installed on your system and that it is the default programme to open .txt files.
2. Then Install [gitpad](https://github.com/github/gitpad) on your system. Note the last I checked the download link was broken, so download it from [here](https://github.com/downloads/github/GitPad/Gitpad.zip) as [explained](https://github.com/blog/975-gitpad-write-your-commits-in-notepad).

Then while committing you should see your favorite text editor popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I used starikovs' solution. I started with a bash window and gave the commands

```
cd ~
touch .bashrc
```

Then I found the .bashrc file in windows explorer, opened it with notepad++ and added

```
PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"
```

so that bash knows where to find Notepad++. (Having Notepad++ in the bash PATH is a useful thing on its own!) Then I pasted his line

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad++.exe -multiInst"
```

into a bash window. I started a new bash window for a git repository to test things with the command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

and the file opened in Notepad++ as hoped.