# GIT core.editor setup on windows along w application PATH reference

Tags: git, command-line, path, notepad++

so i wehnt ahead and opened up my .gitconfig file and manually input the

`[core]
 editor = 'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'`

which would allow me to execute command:
(im trying to setup my .gitignore list)

`"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" .gitignore`

im JUSt not interested in typing this out every time that i need to make a file

SO ive heard something about editing PATH to allow me to replace the above with something like:

`npp .gitignore`

any help would be aprpeciated!

Comment: That would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it quite wrong.

- Git's core.editor setting is used for telling git which editor to launch when it wants your input (e.g. commit messages)
- As for editing .gitignore, you can do it with whichever editor you choose
- You can add the directory (e.g. c:\program files\notepad++) to your PATH through right click on My Computer -> Advanced -> Environment -> SYSTEM -> PATH : add your PATH to the semicolon separated list

Comment: Yeap! this is what i needed ... to add the notepad++ directory reference to the SYSTEM PATH 

thanks!