# Git problem with interactive rebase

Tags: git, msysgit

This is basically what happens:

```
> git rebase -i HEAD~3
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

Pops open my text editor then immediately "completes" the rebase before I even have the chance to do anything. Anyone know what might be causing this?

I'm using msysgit on Windows 7: git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: I've noticed this too, but it only seems to happen once for a given git repository, and then for the second time and each time after that, it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, related to the editor variable in git-config:

[How do I use Notepad++ (or other) with msysgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because Git expects that the text editor will stop and wait until you have finished editing before continuing. Your text editor could start up in such a way that it *appears* that it immediately finished as far as Git can see.

You could try setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to point to a batch file that does something like:

```
start /wait my_editor %*
```

(but this is just a guess and I'm not in a situation to test it right now).

Comment: Very probable, I've seen the same happen on Linux with `gvim`.

Comment: I'll try the batch thing...this worked on my old machine however, and I don't see how my current one would be different. I've tried using the same editor and a different one, both of which have this problem.

Comment: Solved it, turned out to be some weirdness with the way msysgit takes paths. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit

Comment: @larsmans: how did you solve it? I have the same problem on Linux, also with `gvim`

Answer (score 4):

I use Atom - and was getting the same problem.

```bash
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

... fixed it for me straight away.

More info about setting up different code editors can be found here:
https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/

Comment: +1. My `core.editor` was missing the `--wait` part. For VSCode users, use `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` as described in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Notepad++ while I encountered the same issue.

I was in the **Administrator mode** of Notepad++.

Back to normal mode solved my issue.