# Cannot get global mailmap to work

Tags: windows, git

I've been trying to make my .mailmap file to work globally in Windows, without having to put it at the root of each repository.

So I've moved it to C:\Users\.mailmap and added in the config file the following:

```
[mailmap]
    file = 'C:/Users/<username>/.mailmap'
```

But it doesn't work.

I've tried all variations of no-quotes, single quotes, double quotes, single slash, double backslash... and I haven't been able to make it work. I've also tried using a more Windows-friendly file name, like MailMapGlobal.txt (similar to the GitignoreGlobal.txt I have that works just fine).

While researching the problem I've found [this apparently unresolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6524756/385646) from 2011, which is pretty much the same, and I was wondering if there's been any news on this issue in the last 6 years or if there's a known solution that is not listed in that question.

I'm using Windows 7, with git 2.13.2.windows.1

Comment: I have no idea why this would not "just work" on Windows, but will say that there should be no need for quotes: I would expect the no-quotes, forward-slash variant to "just work". But I avoid Windows for a reason, too. :-)

Comment: Well, it doesn't. For example, the global gitignore, which is in the same path, is specified without quotes and double backslash, and it works just fine...

Comment: The doubled backslash makes sense there as `git config` eats one level of backslash quoting, so if you use `a\b\c` style names you'd need `a\\b\\c`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT .mailmap works per repo, but not in global, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524756/git-mailmap-works-per-repo-but-not-in-global-why)