# using Notepad++ for git inside cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, notepad++

This is an extension of this question

[How do I use Notepad++ (or other) with msysgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493#comment13111374_1635493)

i have done all combinations that i can think of for my shell script.  when i have my cygwin console (im using mintty if it matters) i can type

```
npp {file}
```

and the file opens correctly.  but when i do a

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

npp opens with a blank new document, not the interactive file to control the rebase.  any idea why this would be happening?

```
git --version
git version 1.7.9
```

latest version of cygwin on a windows 7 machine and NPP 5.9.8

also, here is my wrapper script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar \
  -nosession -noPlugin "$*"
```

Comment: Cygwin, interesting. My script was to be used with msysgit, in a DOS or mwin bash session. For Cygwin, shouldn't be using cygwin paths? `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/...`

Comment: posix is turned on so windows paths inside cygwin work just fine, besides, i tried it both ways and neither worked.

Comment: have you checked this http://superuser.com/q/168971/11855

Comment: im working on an idea right now, im thinking that since this is a cygwin version of git, maybe the issue is git is passing it a cygwin path and npp doesn't know what to do with it.  im looking at shell scripts that call cygpath to correct it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was correct about my cygwin path issue.  i changed my shell wrapper to this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar \
  -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Excellent (+1). I have edited by original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493#comment13111374_1635493) to include your conclusion (and reference back your answer).

Comment: I'm using cygwin and had some problems with the \ so I changed this to:


#!/bin/sh
'C:/Apps/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"

And now it works for me. Thanks a bunch for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "shell wrapper" here? I'm having this issue with Sublime Text and can't figure it out. When I go to do a Git commit, it opens an empty file that doesn't exist. It looks for a path like this:
"C:\c\Users\Jordan\Desktop\test\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG"

Comment: Did you test your solution, when the filename/filepath being passed to your command line contains a space?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **complete solution without a wrapper script**.

These lines assume that you are using the 64bit version of Windows.

Run the following command from the command prompt (Cygwin):

```sh
git config --global core.editor \
  "'$(cygpath -u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe")' \
  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

---

This is an example of how your **.gitconfig** should look like **after the command**:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /home/Aternus/.gitignore_global
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
    editor = '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

Comment: This could work just with Windows' version of Git, not Cygwin's, because Cygwin's Git would execute Notepad++ with Cygwin's path to the file: `notepad++.exe /home/user/repository/file.extension`. I'm sure Windows Notepad++ won't find such file. Even if you have you repo outside Cygwin's directories, it would look like this: `notepad++.exe /cygdrive/d/repository/file.extension`.

Comment: When I use this, I get an empty notepad window opened when doing interactive rebase for example...

Comment: What's the point of fiddling with _cygpath -u_? You could have simply written `... core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' ...."`. Aside from this, I personally would find the use of a wrapper script easier to maintain and more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a simple script for running arbitrary Windows commands with UNIX-style path arguments:

**cygrun.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -z "$1"; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0" .sh) program [argument]..."
    exit 1
fi

program=$1
shift
if test $# -ge 0; then
    IFS=$'\n'
    exec "$program" $(cygpath -w "$@")
else
    exec "$program"
fi
```

Here's how I can use it in my git config (assuming `cygrun` is a symlink to `cygrun.sh` somewhere in PATH):

```
[core]
    editor = cygrun 'C:/Program Files/Notepad2/Notepad2.exe'
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = cygrun 'C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

This way one script can fits many similar use cases, there's no need to create a separate wrapper every time. It can be convenient to use from command line as well.

Comment: An improved version of my script, which can also be used to run Cygwin tools using Windows paths: https://gist.github.com/gene-pavlovsky/e81c8e18327540f70df4e5296ff3dd15
Use `-w` option to run Windows tools with UNIX paths, and no options (or `-u`) to run Cygwin tools with Windows paths.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=
fi
Notepad2 ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is not empty, convert to Windows format.

Then I set these variables:

```c
export EDITOR=notepad2.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/notepad2.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/2973070/editor)

Answer (score 0):

There's an [existing solution without a wrapper script that looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726568/365237), but with cygwin git and cmd.exe, will just open an empty file every time.

To fix that, you'd need to have this in your .gitconfig (which with --global will reside in your cygwin home folder):

```
[core]
        editor = '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin $(cygpath --windows "${1}")
```

Key thing being `$(cygpath --windows "${1}")` at the end.

Seems this will work on cmd.exe:

```
git config --global core.editor "'/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin $(cygpath --windows ${1})"
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest an alternative simple answer to dealing with the argument file paths to notepad using cygpath.

Create a symbolic link in windows to your home directory under cgywin.
In this way notepad will be able to find the input files through the symbolic link.

On my PC, I opened **cmd** with "**Run as administrator**" and type in the following under `C:\` :

```
    C:\>mklink /D home cygwin64\home
```

With this, you can simply configure git as follows (taken from previous answers) and assuming notepad is installed at the following directory:

```
    git config --global core.editor '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```