# How to Commit in github?

Tags: github

[image: i am getting error when i am trying to commit]

i am getting error sh.exe: notepad: command not found please short out my problem
Thanks

Comment: Is your problem related to github or notepad.exe?

Answer (score 1):

For the commit to GitHub part, you need to add (if you have created an empty yourRepo on GitHub):

```
git config user.name yourGitHubUsername
git config user.email yourGitHubEmail
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin https://yourAccount@github.com/yourAccount/yourRepo
git push -u origin master
```

If that fails because GitHub already created one commit when you initialized your "empty" repo (it can add by default a `README.md` and a `.gitignore`), do a:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git push -u origin master
```

If you really have to call notepad from a mingw session, you can use [this wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210055/6309):

```
#!/bin/sh
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar \
  -nosession -noPlugin "$(cygpath -w "$*")"
```

But remember you can use msysgit from a DOS session as well.

Comment: w2hen i writ this line and enter i am getting  errot sh.exe":remote:command not found

Comment: @Shakti did you type "git remote" or just "remote"? How did you launch your mingw session? Through Git? What version of Git did you install?

Comment: @Shakti that is not how git commands work: you type git xxxx, not xxxx.

Comment: in next section i typed  $git push -u origin master  i am getting following error

Comment: fatal:could not read username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

Comment: What does `git remote -v` returns? And please tell me you did replace `yourGitHubUsername` (or `yourAccount`) and `yourGitHubEmail`, and `yourRepo` by actual values

Comment: i did not replace any thing

Comment: @Shakti Why did you not replace something like `yourGitHubUsername` by... I don't know, *your actual GitHub username*? It was given as a generic example, for you to tailor and adapt to your specific account.

Comment: my user.name  is dany001

Comment: @Shakti ok, I see https://github.com/Dany001/project/commits. So `yourGitHubUsername`  or `yourAccount` equals `Dany001` (the case is important).

Comment: dear sir i did'nt get your mean

Comment: @Shakti "the case is important" means you must replace `yourGitHubUsername` or `yourAccount` by `Dany001`, not `danny001`: You need to respect the upercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: why should i change my username

Comment: @Shakti I am asking you to change the `yourGitHubUsername` (I used in my example) by your actual username on GitHub, which is `Dany001`. I am *not* asking you to change your username on GitHub. Keep `Dany001`.

Comment: are yuo asking user.email or user.name

Comment: You must set, within your local repo, your name and email used for your commit. In order for GitHub to see that it is "you" who did those commits you are about to push, it is important you set `user.name` and `user.email` to your GitHub account name (`Danny001`) and GitHub email.

Comment: YES SIR I CHANGED  USERNAME   FROM TOUR EXAMPLE

Comment: i am using this                                                   git config user.name Dany001
git config user.email sharmarahul696@gmail.com
git add EEADME.md
git commit -m "HIIII"
git remote add origin https://yourAccount@github.com/Dany001/javaprojectdany.git
git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

Seps:
1.git init
2. git status
3. git add .
4. git commit -a
5. git status