# Notepad++ unable to find COMMIT_EDITMSG file

Tags: git, cygwin, notepad++

I'm trying to configure GIT edit commit message with Notepad++. when I do git commit, notepad++ is opening with the error :

> "cannot open file, C:\cygdrive\c\project_path.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
>   cannot be oped. The folder
>   C:\cygdrive\c\project_path.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG doesn't exist."

The folder ./git exists the project _path folder. but I don't understand why  \cygdrive\c is on the path.

I'm using cygwin on Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Notepad++ for git inside cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209660/using-notepad-for-git-inside-cygwin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcygwin%5D+%5Bgit%5D+%22notepad%2B%2B%22

Comment: Your path *C:\cygdrive\c\project...* is wrong.

Comment: @CristiFati I know this path is wrong, the right path is **C:\project_path\.git\**, but notepad is looking to the path **C:\cygdrive\c\project...** which is obviously wrong, and this the issue, I don't know from where notepad is pulling this wrong path.