# How can I open notepad ++ in gitbash?

Tags: git, notepad++

I have some problem with opening editortext in my Git Bash.
Im trying send commit with typing "git commit" without any massage.
I'm trying write it inside my notepad++ and I cannot.
I'm getting message that file "addp-hunk-edit.diff" cannot be opened and I cannot find the solution to this.

When I'm typing "git commit" I'm getting message back "hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file..." and then notepad++ is trying to open but it cant. Cause im getting error like in added link. [1](https://images89.fotosik.pl/183/25be3cff441c31f0gen.png)

Someone had this same error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Notepad++ for git inside cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209660/using-notepad-for-git-inside-cygwin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git%20notepad%2b%2b

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image, the git repository is located under `KursGit'a`.
Notepad++ looks in the path `...\KursGita\.git\...`. The apostrophe seems to be the problem.