# Github - Notepad++

Tags: github, notepad++

I have searched around and can't find anything, so could anyone help me with getting notepad++ to work seamlessly with Github. I would like to be able to open notepad++ and be able to work on files, then when I save (or live) it will show on Github. I have installed everything they say I need to and have the README, but that's all.

Comment: That's not how Git works.  You should work locally, then push to GitHub.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin for Notepad++?
http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1358320/all
You can not save directly on github but you can save and then commit these modified files.

Comment: That is not working with Github. Not sure why though.

Comment: How can I get tortoise git to work with Gthub?

Comment: Maybe : http://dbanck.de/2009/10/08/github-windows-and-tortoisegit-part-1-installing-pulling/ or http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/165

Comment: I have a folder in my documents for Github with folders for my projects, but when I add files it doesn't show up on my online repository.

Comment: I do not use TortoiseGit but TortoiseHG(Mercurial) when I want to send on-line repository (in my case: bitbucket), I have to use Tortoise to synchronize : this is not automatic.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an old question, but I just bumped into it today and thought I'd share my strategy, as the plugin proposed here requires also TortoiseSVN, which is a setup that I don't find as fluid and easy to use as my alternative.

After finding that there's no "stand-alone" plugin you can get for this, I started using [GitHub Desktop App](https://desktop.github.com/). This enables you to set repositories locally, make commits, pulls, pushes, etc. Just login with your account, and then create a local repository for your project.

After creating the repository, just open the files you wish to edit with Notepad++. Make some changes, save and use the GitHub Desktop Application to do all GitHub related stuff. Opposed to the plugin, this app provides a full featured interaction with GitHub.

By the way, if you have two monitors, or a big one, you can just have the two applications open side by side, which emulates similar setups you can find in advanced IDEs (Eclipse, for example). I find this to be even more convenient and fluid than having to open a separate plugin dialogue for doing my Git related stuff. The GitHub Desktop application will even refresh automatically, without any interaction being required from you, after you make any editions to the files (using Notepadd++) or any changes in the file structure (add, rename, move, delete files).

Comment: How does one setup "exteranl editor" from inside Github Desktop? Currenlty (2019Q1) only "Atom" can be setup it seems?