# git commit -- aborting commit prematurely when using notepad++ as default editor

Tags: git, commit

I am trying to commit all changes to my latest repo using

```
git commit -a
```

I have edited global configurations to use notepad++ rather than vim

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files (x86)Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -m"
```

Now, when I try to commit using the first mentioned command, notepad++ will open the COMMIT_EDITMSG file, but the bash shell says "Aborting commit due to empty commit message", then returns to the prompt.

I would simply like to be able to use notepad++ to edit this file and still do the commit without it cancelling it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486342/413399

Comment: Thank you David!  Funny how I didn't see this when searching...  Anyway this solution works great.