# Using Notepad++ as Git Editor without affecting settings

Tags: git, notepad++, git-config

I use and love Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as my go to simple text editor. I have been using it as my default editor for git for a few weeks now and have noticed some funny behavior.

Normally I run Notepad++ with the Tab Bar enabled like so

[image]

However when I use Notepad++ as my git editor I would prefer it to open in the most basic mode possible (mainly no tabs, and in its own instance) I simply want a text editor to log my commit messages and such. The relevant section of my `.gitconfig` is setup as follows

```
[core]
autocrlf = true
editor = "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Using this Notepad++ opens as desired when launched from git, however, the next time I launch Notepad++ normally, it loses my prior settings and does not display the tab bar anymore. It is real annoying to have to update this setting every time I want to use Notepad++ after it is launched from git. Any suggestions as to how I can have Notepad++ work in both situations without the settings affecting each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as I might, I was not able to get either Notepad++, or Notepad++ Portable to work for me in this situation. Notepad++ displayed my initial problem of permanently changing my settings to those set from my `.gitconfig`.

I was also unable to get Notepad++ Portable (http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepadpluspe/) to work as this requires Administrative privileges to run and therefore prompts for UAC every time it launches, which I see as a deal killer.

I ended up using the portable version of Sublime Text 2 (http://www.sublimetext.com/2) as my editor for git, which though it doesn't answer my initial question, was my resolution.

Answer (score 7):

Get a portable version of Notepad++ (http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepadpluspe/) and set up git to use that. In the `Notepad++PE.ini` file add:

```
AdditionalParameters=-multiInst
```

Then use your normal Notepad++ installation with all your settings for normal work.

Comment: Great option, I had considered this, and may have to go this way, but I was wondering if there was a way to use the same exe and preserve the initial settings.

Comment: Ahh alas, I gave this a try and quite lamely, only one instance of either Notepad++ or Notepad++ Portable can be running at the same time. With Notepad++ open I tried to open my git editor (Notepad++Portable) and was graced with an error dialog.

Comment: Another instance of Notepad++ is already running. Please close other instance of Notepad++ before launching Notepad++Portable. I put a screenshot up on http://i1315.photobucket.com/albums/t598/jstromwick/notepateppfail_zps2b345247.jpg

Comment: I was able to start Notepad++Portable while having my normal Notepad++ running by adding `AdditionalParameters=-multiInst`to my `Notepad++PE.ini`

Comment: Yep you're right, I believe I was using an older version of the app previously. I was able to launch both at the same time using `multiInst` and it does indeed appear that they are truly different apps with different settings that do not effect each other. Unfortunately it looks like the installed version of Notepad++PE requires UAC elevation, which fails to launch from git console with `$ Notepad++PE.exe
sh.exe": ./Notepad++PE.exe: Bad file number`

Answer (score 3):

```
[core]
autocrlf = true
editor = "'C:/PROGRA~2/NOTEPA~1/NOTEPA~1.EXE' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the `-notabbar` option and downvote those devils, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635493/1083704 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486342/1083704, who spreaded this heresy over the world.

Answer (score 0):

@Val I agree. This worked for me.

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin
```