# Git How to commit after closing editor?

Tags: git, github

I am using windows machine with notepad++ installed. I configured the editor using the following command

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession"
```

Then I created a new blank repository and added a "New Text Document.txt" file. Now when i execute "git commit" command it opens a new notepad++ instance with the texts.

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   new file:   New Text Document.txt
#
```

Now i save the "COMMIT_EDITMSG" file by clicking save button in Notepad++ and close Notepad++ instance.

My expectation is, all commits are done. 
However if i run "git status" command it still shows file is not commited

```
Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   New Text Document.txt
```

What else i need to do for committing the changes?

Comment: Looks like git does not realize that editor has finished being used. I suggest you use a simple command line editor instead of such a huge GUI beast. Any will do.

Comment: i was using command line editor that was by default set by git in windows 7 machine. But it didn't work either. I can commit by using "git commit -m 'some message' " command..but i wanted to know whats the use of using editor and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

you should look at [Using Notepad++ as Git Editor without affecting settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323968/using-notepad-as-git-editor-without-affecting-settings)
which has this on one of the comments

```
[core]
autocrlf = true
editor = "'C:/PROGRA~2/NOTEPA~1/NOTEPA~1.EXE' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```