# How do you initialize the Git repository?

Tags: git, initialization, repository, directory, init

I created `"my-git-repo"` on my desktop and executed `"~/Desktop/my-git-repo"`. But when I try to run `"git init"` to turn the directory into a `Git repository`, I get this:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: Btw which SO are you using? Windows, ubuntu, other linux, os x?

Comment: As the error message mentions dylib it should be OS X

Comment: @Bjorn Kautler I figured it out. The version that I was using was too new for my OS. I downgraded to 2.2.1 and now it works. But now I'm having difficulty committing a snapshot. When I type "git commit", I get this: "error: cannot run notepad++: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'notepad++'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some problem with git itself.

```
git init
```

Should be enough.

Try to uninstall git and install again

Comment: I figured it out. The version that I was using was too new for my OS. I downgraded to 2.2.1 and now it works. But now I'm having difficulty committing a snapshot. When I type "git commit", I get this: "error: cannot run notepad++: No such file or directory error: unable to start editor 'notepad++' Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."

Comment: try to change the default editor https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration : `core.editor` key

Comment: or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323968/using-notepad-as-git-editor-without-affecting-settings

Comment: In the first article - I tried the command before and it gives the same error. In the second article - My issue is that I'm using a Mac. I had to download Notepad++ through Winebottler. Is it not possible to use Notepad++ with Git on a Mac?

Comment: it should be possible to use Notepad++ yes. Workaround: supply message on commit command: `git commit -m "<message>"`

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I tried to give you a point, but the system won't let me.