# Changing Git core editor to Notepad++ causing issues

Tags: windows, git, notepad++

I use Windows 10 and a while back I changed the default Git editor to `Notepad++`

Now whenever I execute a command that brings up the editor I can't find any way of saving the message & continuing with the command - I end up having to cancel i.e. `CTRL` + `C`

I don't *have* to have `Notepad++` as the editor but I do need to be able to use Git properly.

**What I've tried**

- Restoring the original editor (I wasn't able to find out how)
- Finding a similar problem on Stack Overflow

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486342/6309 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Restoring the original editor (I wasn't able to find out how)

You can try:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git config --unset-all core.editor
git config -l|grep core.editor
```

(`grep` is available if you add your `<git>/usr/bin` to the Windows `%PATH%`.
`<git>` is the path where you have installed git)

If that does not work, you might have to remove it for your local and global config:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git config --local --unset-all core.editor
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
git config -l|grep core.editor
```

Comment: Just executed both commands, after the second one I get: `core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin`