# git pull shows "destructing" messages

Tags: git, git-pull

I did a *git pull* today and got the following:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From bitbucket.org:[...]
   968e1d5..672edb4  develop    -> origin/develop
   911ae33..37250eb  release/fta -> origin/release/fta
destructing 4
destructing 3
destructing 2
destructing 1
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .../[...].cs  | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Some context:

- The pull was unable to do a fast-forward. Therefore I got a merge commit.
- From the point on where my branch diverged from the remote, I had one commit (with 2 file changes) and the remote had one commit (with 1 file changed).

So what are the "destructing X" messages about?
Why are there 4 of them? Two commits with 3 file changes where merged.

Checked git documentation and did some duckduckgo'ing and could not find an answer.

Kind regards

Comment: Do you have any git hooks installed by any chance?

Comment: @JulienLopez No I have not. Needed to check what a git hook is. Found an atlassian tutorial here: [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks). In the hooks directory of my repository, I have only the default hooks, all suffixed with ".sample".

Comment: As far as I know, these messages are not from ordinary git. Have you tried something like `grep -nr "destructing "` in your local repository?

Comment: I fired up the command on my repository, and it came up with two TDF files, which are used for translation in the CMS system (sitecore). But I think aswell that it is not an native GIT message, because if it was, I think I would not be the first one to bump into that. 
GIT is also still working fine. I was just wondering what this message was all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, that message was generated by Notepad++.

Do you have [Notepad++ set as your git commit message editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635493/3991344)?  Additionally, are you using Cygwin?  If so, then pulling and getting a merge commit would have opened Notepad++.  From then, there's a chance that you opened the plugin manager.

Notepad++'s *plugin manager* previously emitted `destructing %d` messages when it was opened, but due to a console usually not being attached, those messages never showed up anywhere.  However, with Cygwin, they *do* appear... but only when you close Notepad++.  The messages also only appear when you open the plugin manager, which can make it hard to figure out the actual cause.

[This has been fixed](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/issues/34), and will be solved in the next release of the plugin manager (which isn't out yet).

The messages only relate to internal disposal from within Notepad++; no actual data was deleted or even changed.  This is just normal behavior for the plugin manager and not something to be worried about.  (I'm not entirely sure why it's 4 occurrences; that's just the number of things that get allocated).