# How to set up a rebase in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: git, bash, rebase

I'm trying to following the instructions on https://help.github.com/articles/using-git-rebase-on-the-command-line/ for interactively rebasing from my initial commit (More specifically, I'm trying to remove all the `bin` and `obj` folders from the history). So once I type in

```
git rebase -i --root
```

I get the following screen as expected, but then I can't figure out how to change the first one to `edit`. Like I can't figure out which button on the keyboard to click. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

[image]

Comment: Check out the basic VIM commands, video tutorials are pretty handy.

Comment: probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit) should be useful to you

Answer (score 12):

Thats pretty easy. You have to change the word `pick` to `edit`
Then you save the file, in your case press `ESC` and then type `:wq`. Then git will start the rebase and you will stop on each commit you want to edit.

Edit: If you don't know how to insert in vim: press `ESC` and then `i` after that you are in insert-mode and as soon as you are finished with typing press `ESC` again and save it as described above.

Comment: I think the OP may be in the same camp as I was; I had no idea this screen was vim. That hint alone is of great help!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a problem in doing squash commit on my Windows CMD and wanted to reproduce the steps I used to do squash commit on my Windows CMD as I felt the previous answer is not a complete guide on doing squash commit in Windows CMD.

Squashing commits into a single commit:

1. git rebase -i HEAD~(Enter number of commits to be squashed)
2. Press "i" to insert
3. Now replace 'pick' with 's' for all unwanted commit messages
4. Press Esc and then type ":wq"
5. The above will open a new console. Remove all the unwanted commit lines
6. Press Esc and then type ":wq" again

Your squash has now been completed.

Now the final step is to push the branch again with the command:-

git push origin (branch-name) -f