# Invoking notepad++ from Git Bash

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, msysgit, git-bash

I am using [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/) in Windows 7. How do I invoke notepad++ from  Git Bash, like we do it with our default notepad?

Like for example

name@usename notepad textfile.txt

Instead I want the file to open with notepad++.

**Note :** I've added notepad++ to my PATH, but still unable to invoke it from commandline.

**Edit**

I tried this in **.gitconfig** -->

[alias] notepad='C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'

but isn't working.

Comment: It's tough to write an alias because of all the special characters needing escaping - the space in 'program files' the brackets in '(x86)' and the plus symbols in 'notepad++'.

Comment: @ColonelPanic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892555/how-do-i-specify-c-program-files-without-a-space-in-it-for-programs-that-cant

Answer (score 63):

So, by default you won't have a .bashrc file so just navigate your to your home directory by typing:

```
cd ~
```

create or edit the .bashrc with vim (or whatever editor you are comfortable with):

```
vim .bashrc
```

Here is the line I had to add to mine (I am running a 64 bit OS so if you aren't don't copy this exactly)

```
alias notepad="/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

If your copy of windows is 32 bit then it should look like this

```
alias notepad="/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

Finally, close and reopen your terminal/bash (or, as noted, run `source ~/.bashrc`), and voila!

Comment: Wow, this is a game-changer! So good! I used: `alias open="/c/Program\ Files\/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`

Comment: Are you sure with it? It still says me that command not found.

Comment: If you haven't closed and reopened your bash client, it may not see the new addition. This gave me a headache for a while on some other scripting I was doing to open VS solutions.

Comment: @JoshGust or you can `source` it. (`source ~/.bashrc')

Comment: Notepad++ is now available for both, 32 bit and 64 bit Windows. So the second snippet will also work in 64 OS.

Answer (score 46):

these are the faster ways to achieve the goal

```
start notepad++ 
start notepad++ <filename>
alias np='start notepad++'
np <filename>
```

tried and tested, just do it!

Answer (score 6):

I added this for my 64-bit machine with 32-bit Notepad++.

```
$ cd ~
$ vim .bash_profile
```

Add this to the file then save:

**64-bit systems**

```
alias npp="/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

**32-bit systems**

```
alias npp="/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

Now you should be able to open any file with notepad++ by entering

```
$ npp [file_name]
```

Comment: think it  ahs to be added to this file `.bashrc`?

Comment: Newer versions of Notepadd++ are natively build for 64-bit systems, so by default it installs to "/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"

Answer (score 5):

I believe git-bash is an actual bash shell, so when it starts, it runs a `.bashrc` file from somewhere (most likely your home directory or the directory git-bash starts in).  Look for that file, and when you find is, add an alias line somewhere for notepad++:

`alias notepad="/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`

Of course use your actual path to Notepad++ there.

Comment: all of this is correct but chances are he doesn't have a .bashrc file yet because he hasn't ever used it. 

Read my comment or create a .bashrc file in your users home directory and add the appropriate path to the application

Comment: you can also use single quotes around double quotes so : alias np='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"'

Answer (score 4):

@SageMage's answer is right on spot.

Just a reminder. You need to close and reopen GitBash after after you make a change in .bashrc in order for it to be activated.

PS: After two years, I hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

The below is [**listed on Udacity's course**](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/sublime) on Git and GitHub. It worked for me:

1. Run the following command in Git Bash after checking the location of
   Notepad++ on your PC.

   ```sh
   echo 'alias npp="C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad\+\+/notepad\+\+.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   Notice how I had to escape characters like the space and the brackets. You can escape any character if you're not sure whether it should be escaped or not. Also make sure to use the alias you want; I chose `npp`.
2. Close and re-open Git Bash
3. Type `npp` in Git Bash, **if it opens then you're good to go.** If not, try the below points:
4. Test *.bashrc* by running the command below in Git Bash

   ```sh
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Retry typing `npp` to start Notepad++. If Notepad++ doesn't start, check the contents of the file *~/.bashrc* created in step 1.
6. To ensure the .*bashrc* file contents are loaded each time you open Git Bash, edit *~/.bash_profile* and add the following two lines. (Reference)

   ```sh
   if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi

   case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
   ```
7. Close and re-open Git Bash. Type `npp` in Git Bash to check it starts correctly.

Comment: I would add to @Amgad's answer that you'll probably have to add escape characters around the parentheses as well!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 
if you haven't created any .bashrc profile or .bash_profile create either of the one using vim or any other editor as others have mentioned

Or

In case you did not have any such editor which can work with git bash yet make one manually by opening a notepad or notepad++ editor  and saving the file at the home directory.

Note: You can check your home directory by using

```
 cd ~

 pwd
```

My Notepad++ path is C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

So for going to any directory to notepad++ directory, I have to go to root directory and then to the required path. 
So here is the line that I had to add to mine .bash_profile

```
alias note="//\/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

'//' takes it to the root directory

**P.S.:**

- You may have to change the path depending on your target directory( notepad++ directory)
- The "Program Files"directory should be written like 'Program\ Files'.
- If your Notepad++ directory is in Program Files (x86) then use 'Program\ Files\ (x86)'

Answer (score 1):

In your .bash profile add

> alias myeditor="'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'"

Give "\\" instead of "\".

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Git Bash on your system/project and type the following command in the Git Bash

   `git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"`
2. Press Enter and if no error occurs, you have successfully set up Notepad++ as your text editor in Git Bash.
   You can also check it by typing the command

   `git config --global core.editor`

[image]

Comment: You explained how to set up the core.editor (which is unnecessary), not how to open/invoke the app related to the file wanted to be opened from git bash, which is achieved by typing `start filename`, start will open the program associated to the file extension

Answer (score 0):

I added the Notepad++ folder to my path, so I can just type `notepad++`

```
$ which notepad++
/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++
```

Comment: @Andi Then notepad++ *isn't* in the PATH used by the git shell. How did you add it to your path?

Answer (score 0):

This config works for me

```
editor = \"/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe\" -multiInst
```

The multiInst argument is just to make it friendlier for interactive edits where you already have notepad++ open. (If Notepad++ is already open and you run the process again, it adds the file to your existing instance and then exits immediately, which git takes to mean you've finished)

Answer (score 0):

I met the cannot find the command issue. 
I figured out that is because I was doing all those vim .bashrc under my working directory. 
It seems I have to do that under the Git Bash home directory...

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/associating-text-editors-with-git

The section under "Using Notepad++ as your editor" provided the answer.

Run the following in Git Bash and you're away.

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

If you want to open up the global git config file after setting up notepad++ use this:

```
$ git config --global -e
```

Answer (score -1):

In your git bash just add:

```
alias npp='notepad++ -multiInst -nosession'
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score -2):

An alias is used with the `git` command, so with the one in your OP, you should be able to run `git notepad`. I don't think this is quite what you want, though. If you correctly added notepad++ to your PATH variable, then you should be able to just do `notepad++`. You can check this by running `which notepad++`. If this doesn't give the full path to `notepad++`, then the PATH isn't set correctly.