# Trying to setup a new editor in git

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I'm trying to find a good alternative to the VI editor that comes with my git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0 installed on my windows XP box.  I've looked through the forums here and tried some of their suggestions.  I must be missing something because they aren't working for me.  I've tried this from the git command line:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst"
```

I also tried another way that used a shell.  There I created a folder named shell on the root of C:  I then created a sh file named npp.sh with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
"c:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst "$*"
```

after that I entered this command:

```
git config --global core.editor C:/shell/npp.sh
```

In both cases if I enter notepad++ on the git command line I get the message `sh.exe": notepad++: command not found`.

Comment: In the first case are accidentally truncate the closing `"` when coping/pasting a command?

Comment: Yes that's what happened when copying to this forum.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `I'm trying to find a good alternative to the VI editor` . i do not think you will find the editor better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be surprisingly difficult. `/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe` executes fine from Git bash, but doesn't seem to work with `git config core.editor`.

However, you can create a [Bash *alias*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Aliases) for Notepad++ and use that as your `core.editor`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532226/354577) for details.

Comment: when I hover the mouse over the quick launch icon it displays Git Bash twice so I guess I have Git Bash. Do I leave the quotes the same? I didn't know there were different flavors of Git, is there a better one for Windows?

Comment: You should be able to leave the quotes the same. Git bash is fine, but it uses different pathing from `cmd.exe` (Unix-style instead of Windows-style).

Comment: I changed C:/ to /c/ but no luck.

Comment: @jimeast, strangely `/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe` executes fine from Git bash, but doesn't seem to work with `git config core.editor`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532226/354577) might be useful to you.

Comment: now I have created .bashrc in the home directory with the line alias
npp="/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" and in .gitconfig core I have editor = "'/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++.exe' -multiInst" weather I try npp or notepad++ it fails with the message sh.exe": notepad++/npp command not found.  The good thing is I'm getting to like vim.

Comment: I spoke too soon I didn't realize I had to restart the terminal window for my changes to take effect now the alias works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and the git documentation enlightened me.

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/associating-text-editors-with-git

The section under "Using Notepad++ as your editor" provided the answer.

Run the following in Git Bash and you're away.

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

If you want to open up the global git config file after setting up notepad++ use this:

```
$ git config --global -e
```