# Multiple spaces in command CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

Ok so i am trying to flash a hex file onto my arduino pro micro following this sorta guide:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/69woay/hand_built_keypad_gateron_blues_first_hand_wire/

And I am really struggling with step 2. The problem that i am having is that my thing (Not sure what to call it) looks like this:

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM5 -b57600 -D -Uflash:wC:"\Users\My Name\Desktop\Layout\layout.hex:i""
```

I am getting a this error:

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Which i tried fixing with the speech marks following these recommendations:

[How do I specify C:\Program Files without a space in it for programs that can't handle spaces in file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892555/how-do-i-specify-c-program-files-without-a-space-in-it-for-programs-that-cant)

[How to use spaces in CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-to-use-spaces-in-cmd)

So that's the issue i am probably making one minor mistake or many major ones, but you help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should work -- or at least give a different error -- if you remove first `"` and the last one.

Comment: ... although it would be easier to move your arduino installation to a folder whose path doesn't contain spaces. It's a nuisance to have to quote all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a simpler example. You might try to run `C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myprogram` like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myprogram --parameter:value
```

It doesn't work because the first thing CMD does is split on spaces. This is called *tokenisation` and the result is a list of *tokens*:

- `C:\Program`
- `Files`
- `(x86)\myapp\myprogram`
- `--parameter:value`

Then it takes the first token, `C:\Program` and tries to find a file with that name.

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The tokenisation routine pays attention to quotes. When it encounters a quote, it strips it, then it doesn't treat spaces as token separators, until it encounters the next quote.

So:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myprogram" --parameter:value
```

Tokenises to:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myprogram`
- `--parameter:value`

For some reason in your example you have put more quotes around the whole thing:

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myprogram" --parameter:value"
```

Tokenisation treats the double `"` as a literal `""`, so now it tokenises to:

- `""C:\Program Files`
- `(x86)\myapp\myprogram`
- `--parameter:value`

So you get an error because there is no executable file `""C:\Program Files`.

Understand how quoting and tokenisation works. Make sense of the commands rather than blindly copying them, and you should be able to solve this.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man! Fantastic answer, really saved my bacon

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze your string

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM5 -b57600 -D -Uflash:wC:"\Users\My Name\Desktop\Layout\layout.hex:i""
```

The problem occurs right away with your double quote "". This is interpreted as an empty string between these two quotes. Thus making your C:\Program Files end up outside quotes.

Try this instead

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM5 -b57600 -D -Uflash:wC:"\Users\My Name\Desktop\Layout\layout.hex:i"
```