# Illegal character in path at index , Tomcat SSL connector path

Tags: java, tomcat

I have set up an SSL connector in Tomcat 9 server.xml with this path for the keystore:

```
c:/Program Files/OSS/
```

and I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 10
```

I suppose is the space between `Program` and `Files`, how can I escape it?

Comment: there is a space I think which in connector you can wrap it with Quotes or you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892555/how-do-i-specify-c-program-files-without-a-space-in-it-for-programs-that-cant

or keep the file in a location where there is no space.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue replacing the space with `%20`