# configurate of hadoop and spark

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I install hadoop and spark in my windows 11
I put the path in my env variable

```
"C:\BigData\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2"
"C:\BigData\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\sbin"  
"C:\BigData\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\bin" 
"C:\BigData\hadoop-3.2.2\bin"
```

and i install jdk 1.8 and i put the path java_home
and when i was to excute the spark whith this cmd
"spark-shell"
i have this problem

```
"he system cannot find the path specified."
```

what is the solution ?

Comment: Show us the output from `echo %PATH%`. Otherwise, cd into the directory with that command and run it there

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>echo %PATH%
";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin;C:\BigData\hadoop-3.2.2\bin;C:\BigData\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\bin;C:\BigData\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\sbin;C:\BigData\hadoop-3.2.2\sbin"

Comment: Spark / Hadoop doesn't like having spaces in your path. Reinstall Java somewhere else like `C:\Java` or use `C:\PROGRA~1` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/892568/2308683 . Also, you should be able to use Java 11 instead