# Hadoop commands say JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm getting the following error while I give Hadoop commands (pls refer pic) [image]

Someone tell me how to fix it.

**Note**:
**Java Home local location:** "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20"
**Hadoop Home location:** "D:\Hadoop\hadoop-3.3.5"

Answer (score 0):

1. Hadoop documentation doesn't suggest running it with anything higher than Java 11, so install that, and reset JAVA_HOME
2. Hadoop on Windows does not want spaces in any file paths. Meaning your `JAVA_HOME`  including `Program Files` is a problem. Refer [How do I specify C:\Program Files without a space in it for programs that can't handle spaces in file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892555/how-do-i-specify-c-program-files-without-a-space-in-it-for-programs-that-cant)
3. You'll additionally need `hadoop.dll` placed in `C:\System32` and `winutils.exe` placed in `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` that have been compiled for Hadoop 3.3.5 after fixing the Java issue. Both of these are separate downloads and not included with Hadoop. Otherwise, you should use WSL2 terminal to run any of these commands since Hadoop prefers to run in a Linux environment